# Como selecionar registros que não possuem relacionamentos em uma tabela no node/adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonisjs, lucid

Eu possuo três tabelas:

```
students
------------
id INT
name VARCHAR

class
-----------
id INT
description VARCHAR

student_classes
--------
id INT
student_id (FOREIGN KEY of students.id)
class_id (FOREIGN KEY of class.id)
```

Como eu posso retornar todos os registros da tabela `class` que não possui relacionamento de um determinado aluno em `student_classes`?

Eu recebo o valor de `student_id` em `request.params.student_id`, eu tentei algo como:

```
async getAvailableClassesOfAStudent({ request }){
  const classes = await Database
    .query()
    .select('class.*')
    .from('class')
    .leftJoin('student_classes', 'class.id', 'student_classes.class_id')
    .whereNotIn('student_classes.student_id', request.params.student_id) 

  return classes 
}
```

Estou tendo como retorno:

> select "class".* from "class" left join "student_classes" on
>   "class"."id" = "student_classes"."class_id" where
>   "student_classes"."student_id" not in $1 - syntax error at or near
>   "$1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura Adonis oferece a possibilidade de estabelecer relacionamentos no nível do modelo.

Dito o que você tem um relacionamento: muitos para muitos

Seu modelo de aluno deve conter o seguinte

```
class Student extends Model {
    classes () {
        return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Class')
   }
}
```

Agora seu modelo de classe deve conter o seguinte

```
class Class extends Model   {
    students () {
        return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Student')
   }
}
```

- Use o método chamado: "doesntHave()" para trazer essas aulas sem um aluno registrado

  ```
  const withOutClass = Class.query().doesntHave('students').fetch()
  ```

Enlaces útiles:

- [método "doesn't Have"](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/relationships#_doesnthave)
- [relacionamentos em lúcido](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/relationships#_belongs_to_many)

Answer (score 0):

Se alguém precisar de algo parecido, eu consegui desta forma:

```
// Retorna as classes que um estudante pode se vincular
async getClassesDisponiveisEstudante({ request }){
  const arrayClassesVinculadasEstudante = await Database
    .query()
    .select('class.id')
    .where('student_classes.student_id', request.params.student_id)
    .from('student_classes')
    .innerJoin('class', 'class.id', 'student_classes.class_id')
    .pluck('class.id')

  const classesDisponveis = await Classe.query()
                            .whereNotIn('id', arrayClassesVinculadasEstudante)
                            .fetch()

  return classesDisponveis 
}
```